# Create tag full-thrust

Tags: feature-request

Full-Thrust is an awesome spaceship wargame by Ground Zero Games.

I am posting one question regarding it, but I see there is not yet a tag for it.

Should one be created?

Comment: I have created the tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags can only be created after a question relating to the tag has been asked. Once you have asked your question a user with enough reputation will create and add the correct tag for you.

One thing to remember is that once the tag is created you can go and create a tag wiki for it so that people have more information about the game and the tag is more likely to stay around.

Comment: Shall I add a link to the question in my request?

Comment: @MarcoBolis There shouldn't be a need as people will see the question and notice the tags are off and fix it if they can.